# cannot set property 'overflow' of null

Tags: android, google-api, google-visualization

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

webView loads this html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
                    ['2004', 1000, 400],
                    ['2005', 1170, 460],
                    ['2006', 660, 1120],
                    ['2007', 1030, 540]
                ]);
                var options = {title: 'Company Performance'};
                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='chart_div' style='width: 900px; height: 500px;'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's code from Google's example [Visualization: Line Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)

webView shows text `cannot set property 'overflow' of null`
How fix it?

Comment: I put one-line-html-code for simple java test code, any way, thanks

Comment: Can you kindly clarify the Android / Browser version, so your post will be more useful for other readers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are referring to is thrown from javascript, i guess (otherwise the app would crash)?

What Android OS Version are you trying to do this on? If it's 2.x, you won't get far unless your Google Chart uses a fallback renderer such as [CanVg](https://code.google.com/p/canvg/) (i know highcharts uses canvg with success for that), because the WebView doesn't know svg.

Comment: Can I use it like this `<script type='text/javascript' src='../canvg.js' ></script><script type='text/javascript' src='../rgbcolor.js' >` and then same Google Chart code?

Comment: Not so simple, google charts needs to send the svg data to CanVg instead of writing it directly into the browser DOM. As a fallback for those older devices you could use the (deprecated) Google Image Charts API https://developers.google.com/chart/image/ or give http://www.highcharts.com/ a try (which works on all, also offline). Otherwise i'd search the web for examples of using google charts with canVg, but at first glance i couldn't find any.

Comment: Here's a nice article on the problem and how they solved it for KendoUI: http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-02-17/using_svg_on_android_2_x_and_kendo_ui_dataviz.aspx . Doesn't actually look as complicated as it sounds. Use Modernizr to detect if the browser has SVG, and if not, take the SVG data from google charts and throw it at canvg, there you go.