# Android 2.3.x with google charts

Tags: android, svg, google-visualization, android-browser

In my application I use Google charts.
The problem is that Android 2.3.x browser doesn't support svg.
I got the next error: `cannot set property 'overflow' of null`

After some research I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195808/cannot-set-property-overflow-of-null) with reference to [canvg](https://code.google.com/p/canvg/)

my code:

```
<div id="Wrapper">      
        <div id="titlewrapper"><div id="title" class="rounded-corners">qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm</div></div>
        <div id="chart_div" style="position: relative;">
            <div dir="ltr" style="position: relative; width: 1584px; height: 531px;">
                <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                    <svg width="1584" height="531" style="overflow: hidden;">
                        // SVG CONTENT
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The Google charts code is added inside `#chart_div`.
My question is how can I use `canvg` or any other tool to support the chart in Android 2.3.x browsers?

**- Edit:**
I think to use:

```
//load '../path/to/your.svg' in the canvas with id = 'canvas'
  canvg('canvas', '../path/to/your.svg')
```

How to get reference to that SVG?

Comment: Doesn't google charts support output to PNG?

Comment: In my case I need interactive chart so PNG doesn't good for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic data it's almost impossible see @asgallant answer.
 
Google charts uses SVG and Android 2.3.x browser doesn't support that.
I found a good canvas based alternatives [Flotr2](http://www.humblesoftware.com/flotr2/) and [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/)

Comment: It is possible on Android 2.x by with CanVg [http://code.google.com/p/canvg/] as seen with Highcharts [http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts]. You cannot expect a fluid live update  though, maybe 1-2 frames/s on device. 

Flotr2, Chart.js or Flot [http://www.flotcharts.org/] may provide alternatives for many visualisation needs with much less overhead.

Answer (score 1):

If the canvg library you are using is the same one I am thinking of, I believe you can pass a reference to the `<svg>` element in your DOM to the `canvg` function:

```
var svg = document.querySelector('#chart_div svg');
canvg('canvas', svg);
```

You will probably want to put that in a "ready" event handler for whatever chart you are drawing:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var svg = document.querySelector('#chart_div svg');
    canvg('canvas', svg);
});
```

That will only work, however, if the SVG actually gets written to the DOM.  I don't know if the Android 2.3.x browser will actually allow the invalid svg element to be written to the DOM.

Comment: I tried that, but in Android 2.3.x the 'ready' event doen't called, only 'error' event and seems there is no SVG in the DOM.

Comment: If the Visualization API can't write the SVG to the DOM, then you can't use the canvg function to convert it to a canvas element.  If your chart doesn't have a dynamic data source, you could open the chart in another browser (Chrome), and copy the SVG to a file.  If you put that file on your server, you could have the canvg function pull the SVG data from the file instead of trying to get it directly from the Visualization API.

Comment: You are right I found an alternative 'Flotr2'. Thank you anyway